# SQL Joining One Table to a Selection of Rows from Second Table that Contains a Max Value per Group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of Cases with info like the following -

| ID | CaseName | Date | Occupation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | John | 2020-01-01 | Joiner |
| 12 | Mark | 2019-10-10 | Mechanic |

And a table of Financial information like the following -

| ID | CaseID | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 2020-01-01 | 1,000 |
| 2 | 11 | 2020-02-03 | 2,000 |
| 3 | 12 | 2019-10-10 | 3,000 |
| 4 | 12 | 2019-12-25 | 4,000 |

What I need to produce is a list of Cases including details of the most recent Financial value, for example -

| ID | CaseName | Occupation | Lastest Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | John | Joiner | 2,000 |
| 12 | Mark | Mechanic | 4,000 |

Now I can join my tables easy enough with -

```
SELECT *
FROM Cases AS c
LEFT JOIN Financial AS f ON f.CaseID = c.ID
```

And I can find the most recent date per case from the financial table with -

```
SELECT CaseID, MAX(Date) AS LastDate
FROM Financial 
GROUP BY CaseID
```

But I am struggling to find a way to bring these two together to produce the required results as per the table set out above.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method is window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cases c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT f.*, MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY CaseId) as max_date
      FROM Financial f
     ) f
     ON f.CaseID = c.ID AND f.max_date = f.date;
```